# Mongodb spontaneously deleted all table records

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have mongodb running on an aws ubuntu EC2 instance and overnight it seems to have spontaneously emptied the database. The tables are all still in place but there are no longer any records in any of them. What could possibly have happened? The system has been running flawlessly for months. I've tried repairing the database but no joy there.

Comment: Perhaps you were hacked?

Comment: @THelper It's possible but when I look in the mongodb data folder there are very large 'local' files in there which suggests the data is still there it's just not being loaded by mongodb